# JavaFX Single Selection between Two TableViews

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I have two different Tableview on the same AnchorPane, that only one of them can have a selected cell at any time.

So if the user select one cell from one TableView the and there was a previous selected cell in the other one it has to be unselected.

Comment: Do you mean if a cell of `TableView Foo` is selected then you you unselect (if something was selected in the `TableView Bar`) ? So you can only have one cell selected at a time?

Comment: yeah, the thing is, that i need to Tableviews at the same time and for editing them (the cells in the tables) it is necessary that only one cell from both tables is selected at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just register listeners with each table's selection model, and clear the selection in the other table if something is selected in the current table:

```
    table1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
        if (newItem != null) {
            table2.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }
    });

    table2.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
        if (newItem != null) {
            table1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }
    });
```